# websphere "Application not installed" error

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, application-server

I have a strange error. I am trying to install an ear in websphere 8. After the installation is successfully completed from the console, I try to start the application and it throws an error. In the system out logs, I get the error "Application not installed". Even stranger, when I try to go into installedapps folder for that server, it is empty.
I have installed the app many times before but never encountered this problem. Point to note here is that it is a new installation of the websphere server (after the previous server had crashed)

Comment: Are you sure, you have saved configuration after successful installation? Check in the SystemOut.log if you have any exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably deploying to a federated environment. So the deployment itself is done on the Deployment Manager (DMGR) node and saved into the master repository. Then you have to sync the node (or wait for it to happen periodicaly) to propagate the changes to the actual node on which the app should run.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/uagt_rnodes.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0